# Sending json data to google form with textarea and select tag

Tags: json, ajax, url, google-forms

I created an application which sends json data to a google form with ajax. My problem is that I'm not able to send all the data I wish, which means that I'm not able to send some content inside a textarea and a select tag. I'm working with the url, unfortunately I had to use some hidden content in order to move some data to from a page to another page, if I wont' I'm not able to get some data.

Here is my code: The javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  function postContactToGoogle() {
    var full_name = getParameterByName('full_name');
    var home_address = getParameterByName('home_address');
    var email = getParameterByName('email');
    var phone_number = getParameterByName('phone_number');
    var condition = getParameterByName('condition');
    var extra = getParameterByName('extra');
    var when_to_sell = getParameterByName('when_to_sell');
    console.log(full_name, home_address, email, phone_number, condition, extra, when_to_sell);
    var google_url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdqMQL_dzhdFSVpuVtlcfIa4xHe9DNP8yozB1ncAB2e_byBJQ/formResponse";

    if (full_name !== "" || email !== "" || phone_number !== "" || home_address !== "" || condition !== "" || extra !== "" || when_to_sell !== "")
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: google_url,
        data: { 
          "entry.515947838": full_name,
          "entry.190795925": email,
          "entry.1306603567": phone_number,
          "entry.1032461271": home_address,
          "entry.100378601": condition,
          "entry.637314286": extra,
          "entry.608122467": when_to_sell
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: {
          0: function () {
          },
          200: function () {
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
  postContactToGoogle();
});
```

And here's the html which is creating me a lot of problem: This is a page when I'm collecting some data that I will later send with the ajax

```
<form action="step-3.html" id="form-step2">
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <label for="condition">What conditions is the property in?</label>
          <select id="condition" name="condition">
            <option value="Good">Good</option>
            <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
            <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <label for="extra">Any updates, amenities or extras?</label> 
          <textarea name="extra" id="extra" placeholder="e.g: recent reno, pool etc." rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <label for="when_to_sell">When do you want to sell?</label>
          <select id="when_to_sell" name="when_to_sell">
            <option value="Immediately">Immediately</option>
            <option value="Next 1-3 months">Next 1-3 months</option>
            <option value="Next 3-6 months">Next 3-6 months</option> 
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <label>Are you currently working with a Real Estate Agent?*</label>
          <input checked="checked" id="working_for_real_estate_agent_no" name="working_for_real_estate_agent" type="radio" />
          <label class="radio-label" for="working_for_real_estate_agent_no">No</label>
          <input id="working_for_real_estate_agent_yes" name="working_for_real_estate_agent" type="radio" />
          <label class="radio-label" for="working_for_real_estate_agent_yes">Yes, I am working with a Realtor.</label>
          <div class="asteriks">*We ask this to ensure there is no conflict of interest.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <input id="home_address" name="home_address" type="hidden" />
          <div class="home-evaluation-option-container">
            <div class="home-evaluation-option">
              <input id="exact-market-value" name="exact-market-value" type="button" value="Send Property Details" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And here is the hack that I tried, which unfortunately works only with the input tag:

```
<form action="step-4.html" id="form-step2">
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <input name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" type="input" data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min1" data-validation-error-msg="Please, insert your name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="input" data-validation="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-control full-width">
          <input id="phone_number" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" type="input" name="home-phone" data-validation="number"  />
        </div>

        <input id="home_address" name="home_address" type="hidden" class="hide" />

        <select id="condition" name="condition" class="hide">
          <option value="Good">Good</option>
          <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
          <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="extra" id="extra" class="hide"></textarea>
        <select id="when_to_sell" name="when_to_sell" class="hide">
          <option value="Immediately">Immediately</option>
          <option value="Next 1-3 months">Next 1-3 months</option>
          <option value="Next 3-6 months">Next 3-6 months</option> 
        </select>

        <div class="form-control submit-button">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Generate Report" />
        </div>
      </form>
```

Any thought in order to collect data from a select or a text area?

Here is the page where you can find the code in action:

http://homeworth.online/hockinghomesteam/

Comment: Is your function: `getParameterByName('extra')` getting the value out of the textarea element?

Comment: Yes, it supposes to do that, but I'm receiving a null value

Comment: I have no idea what the `getParameterByName()` function is doing.  It's executing a RegEx match, but I don't see how it would ever get the value out of the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can get the value out of a textarea element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="idExtra_Info">
Some content
</textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("idExtra_Info").value;
    alert(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem of my code is that I have few forms. The first one is on the first page, and the one that I need is on the second page. Unluckily for me, I will retrieve all the data in the third page (with ajax and jquery). For this reason I'm using the url and I'm not using the .val method or the .value with javascript. For the same reason I'm hiding the form field, in order to send all the data I gather to the last page. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Every time that the user goes to a new page, does your website serve all new content?

Comment: Can you explain as better your question? I guess so, I mean in some way I was able to send the data to the url to the first to the third page, adding the form field input and hidden them with css